# Центрирование блока с дивами на флоате

Tags: html, css3, internet-explorer

В современных браузерах код ниже работает великолепно, однако на ie11, происходят баги с main'ом, в чем может быть причина??

Comment: А где код который ниже?

Comment: кстати, тег main поддерживается с 12 IE

Comment: Ясно, попробую щас убрать, протещу

Comment: Данный вопрос не содержит кода (поставил минус), поэтому его ценность для сообщества невелика, а спрашивающий уже получил ответ. Поэтому предлагаю вопрос закрыть и рекомендовать автору доработать вопрос, чтобы он не был [удалён со временем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/213987).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег `main` не поддерживается в IE11 - отсюда баги, спасибо @Air